# Adding and removing "is-invalid" class from CodeBehind in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I'm creating an ASP site where the user has to fill out a form. Textboxes, dropdownlists, and I'm using Bootstrap 4 for the style and the whole content is in an update panel so the page feels responsive without having to do a full postback.

So when the user hits the submit button, I'm checking if any of the textboxes or dropdownlists are empty. If they are, I don't insert into the database, and I append "is-invalid" to the empty fields' CssClass.

`Control.CssClass += " is-invalid";`

Up to this point, it's all fine. The empty fields get red.

But then if the user fills in the empty fields and click on the submit again, the fields remain red, even though I replace the "is-invalid" with nothing.

`Control.CssClass.Replace(" is-invalid", "");`

So my question is, why doesn't the red disappear? If changing the CssClass works from the CodeBehind when appending, then why doesn't it work when I'm removing?

PS.: I know I could use javascript for it, but I'd prefer the whole checking step to be at one place, instead of one half of it being .cs and the other half of it being javascript. But if I can't remove from the CodeBehind, then I'm going to use javascript, but I'm hoping there is a solution.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Control.CssClass.Replace(" is-invalid", "");`

That takes the `string` from the `CssClass` property, creates a new string without the `is-invalid` value, and then throws the new string away. The value of the property will not be changed.

If you want to modify the value of the property, you need to update it:

```
Control.CssClass = Control.CssClass.Replace(" is-invalid", "");
```

Comment: That was it. Man, what a rookie mistake of me. For some reason I was in the belief that .Replace would modify the original string already. But it makes sense that it does not. 
Thanks, you saved me a few hours of sensless frustration, it works great now!

Answer (score 0):

Where in the page lifecycle have you implemented this? It sounds like a good [first place to look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)).

It would also be helpful to see your code.

Comment: Posting my whole code would be quite a lot, but basically I'm just adding/removing the " is-invalid" to/from the given controls' CssClass in the OnClick event of the submit button. The click of the submit button refreshes the update panel and in the process adds/removes the CssClass. And while adding the class works, removing the class seems to have no effect. So the question is, why does it only work one way?

Comment: When you inspect the page, do you see the class you're trying to apply available at the time you expect to see it applied? Seems strange it wouldn't apply the style unless it didn't exist in the context in which you're attempting to apply it.

Maybe also have a look at your master page (if used) and see if there's an issue where you're loading its stylesheet vs styles you're using at the page level.